# Invalid syntax for except ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.3, except

When i run this code (Python 3.3):

```
counter=0
score=0
import random
a = random.randint(1,25)
b = random.randint(1,25)
c=a+b
try:
    answer=int(input("What is "+str(a)+" + "+str(b)+" ? ")                
    if answer == c:
        score=score+1
        print("Well done!")
        print("Your score is "+str(score)+".")
        print("")
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        print("Thats wrong. The correct asnwer is: "+str(c)+".")
        print("Your score is "+str(score)+".")
        print("")
        counter = counter + 1
except ValueError:
       print("sadas")
```

I says "invalid syntax" and it highlight the colon from "if answer == c:" red.

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis on previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
answer=int(input("What is "+str(a)+" + "+str(b)+" ? ")                
#         ^     ^                                    ^?
#         |      \----------------------------------/ |
#          \-----------------------------------------/
```

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know about that feature. I have accepted your answer.